# Change event do not catch option chosen selected, Backbone

Tags: backbone.js

Having the following view:

```
someView = Backbone.View.extend({
   events : {
       'change #selectID' : 'checkSelect'
   },

   checkSelect : function(e) {
      console.log(e);
   }
});
```

I wonder if possible to the selected option from the select tag, considering this select is rendered with data injected from a collection.

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the value of the select with `$(e.target).val()` as in:

```
var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
    events : {
       'change #selectID' : 'checkSelect'
   },
   checkSelect : function(e) {
       var selectValue = $(e.target).val();
       console.log(selectValue);
   }
});
```

Check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a0L7vv65/)